# Change language of guest session to something else but the system wide language

Tags: language-support, guest-session

How can I permanently change the language of Lubuntu's guest account? I have installed Lubuntu 14.04 in German, but for my collegues who use the guest account from time to time, English would be much more helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a "special purpose user" as explained at

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/CustomizeGuestSession

Log in to that user account and use Language Support to change the language to English.

*Edit:*

There is an alternative (and simpler) solution, for the case

1. you don't want to customize the guest session feature in any other way but changing the language, and
2. you don't mind that the login screen is displayed in English.

In that case you can

- Open *Language Support*
- Change the language to English
- Click the **Apply System-Wide** button
- Change the language back to German

Comment: The guideline under "Edit" was exactly what I was looking for; it works fine.